# Own Apple products for $1 for business?

Tags: price

I was looking for ways to save money for a small business on Apple products. While I find that Apple makes the best products, it'll be too expensive for a new business, and will most likely seek some other company.

However, I saw this...
[image]
...on the [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/us_smb_78313/shop/browse/finance/lease).

In detail, what does "Own It" mean? I'm doubting that only $1 comes out of pocket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text indicates that you pay $1 **at the end of the financing term**. So no, you pay $1 in addition to whatever agreement you sign with Apple, not $1 in total.

This is essentially a **lease with option to buy**.

Comment: Isn't this question a shopping question?

Comment: @William It's rather a "help me understand this financing offer from Apple" question. Which is maybe a bit unusual (as we don't get many of these) but not really off-topic per se.